# align inner div to center

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div, inner div & outer div. How to align inner div to center?

Here is my source code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="AdminHomePage.php?id=logout">Manage Staff</a>
</div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.menu{
    margin: 100px auto;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.9;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000000;
    width:300px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.menu a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

[image]

The outer div is on center, but the inner one is align left. How to align it to center?

Comment: `Text-align:center` on `menu`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add text-align: center; to your parent divs css

```css
.menu{
    margin: 100px auto;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.9;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000000;
    width:300px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <a href="AdminHomePage.php?id=logout">Manage Staff</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The a element is displaying inline. Which will cause it to align as you want to align your text.

In that case you could use

```
.menu {
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you want your a to be 100% wide you can display it as a block, and center within the a element.

```
.menu a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set the the property "text-align" in the .menu class.

```
.menu{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu {
    text-align: center;
}

**if you want to make whole width click-able for your link, you can use "display:block" property.
.menu a {
    display : block;
}
```